# Filter WPF combobox to items that contain typed string

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox, filter

I am having trouble figuring out how to filter a combobox to only show the items that contain the text that has been entered so far.

Here is the function that builds the datatable that the combobox binds to:

```
Function users() As DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow
        Dim idCoulumn As DataColumn
        Dim nameCoulumn As DataColumn

        dt = New DataTable()
        idCoulumn = New DataColumn("ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
        nameCoulumn = New DataColumn("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"))

        dt.Columns.Add(idCoulumn)
        dt.Columns.Add(nameCoulumn)

        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("ID") = 1
        dr("Name") = "Zuse, Konrad"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)

        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("ID") = 2
        dr("Name") = "Torvalds, Linus"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)

        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr("ID") = 3
        dr("Name") = "Babbage, Charles"
        dt.Rows.Add(dr)

        ds.Tables.Add(dt)

        Return dt

    End Function
```

How would I program it to only show the Linus and Zuse entries if I typed "u"?

I have tried something like this but I don't really understand what to do:

```
Private Sub userKeyUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs) Handles cb_user.KeyUp
    cb_user.IsDropDownOpen = True
    cb_user.Items.Filter = Function(item)
                               Return item.ToString().Contains(cb_user.Text.Trim())
                           End Function
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ:

```
Dim query = (From dr As DataRow In dt.Rows Where dr("Name").ToString.Contains("Linus")).ToArray()
```

Lambda:

```
Dim query = dt.Rows.AsEnumerable.Where(Function(dr) dr("Name").ToString.Contains("Linus")).ToArray()
```

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand where I would put this in my code.

Comment: The textChanged event if it is a textbox. Clear the items, run the query, load the combobox. This combobox does not require databinding.

Comment: The other route is to use a CollectionViewSource and you apply the query to that. At least that works for Entity Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this control https://www.nuget.org/packages/THEFilteredComboBox/ I think it would be sufficient in your case